# Winforms Resource missing after strange migration

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms window that was imported from another project. It works fine so far but as soon as I edit the From in the Visual Studion designer the designer.cs file does change.

For exsample:

```
this.periodLimitCheckBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

will turn into

```
periodLimitCheckBox.Font = (System.Drawing.Font)resources.GetObject("periodLimitCheckBox.Font");
```

Not too bad but afterwards the program is not able to find this resource. I get an error doing runtime as soon as I open the window:

*'Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "CompanyName.Form.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly.*

How can I fix this and why is it converted at all. Both projects use the same Visual Studio Version.

Comment: Was one framework and the other core?

Comment: The migration itself seems to be related to this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/winforms-codegen-update/. And it looks like some information has been moved to the `resources' file, but that resource is missing.

Comment: @flackoverstow The newer project can be compiled as core but it also have framework build options.